# MPChart dont show axis labels at fit screen

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I'm using mpchart library version: 3.1.0
The chart is a horizontal bar chart.

Here is my code:

```
   chart.description.isEnabled = false


    val xAxis = chart.xAxis
    xAxis.position = XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
    xAxis.typeface = typeface
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true)
    xAxis.granularity = 1f 

    val xAxisLabel: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    xAxisLabel.add("test_1")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_2")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_3")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_4")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_5")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_6")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_7")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_8")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_9")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_10")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_11")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_12")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_13")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_14")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_15")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_16")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_17")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_18")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_19")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_20")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_21")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_22")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_23")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_24")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_25")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_26")
    xAxisLabel.add("test_27")


    val yVals1 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
    for (i in 0 until xAxisLabel.size) {
        val newBEntry = BarEntry(i.toFloat(), i + 1.toFloat())
        yVals1.add(newBEntry)
    }

    chart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisLabel);

    val set1: BarDataSet
    set1 = BarDataSet(yVals1, "استان")
    val dataSets = ArrayList<IBarDataSet>()
    dataSets.add(set1)
    val data = BarData(dataSets)
    data.setValueTypeface(typeface)

    chart.setPinchZoom(true)

    chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);

    chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaximum(50f);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0f);

    chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false)

    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

    chart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);

    chart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
    chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

    chart.setDrawBorders(false);

    chart.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
    chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false

    chart.xAxis.setAxisMaximum(26.5f);
    chart.xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    chart.xAxis.spaceMin = 0f
    chart.xAxis.spaceMax = 1f


    chart.fitScreen();

    chart.data = data
```

But the chart Xaxis labels skipped in fit screen.

[image]

When I zoom in to last zoom level all label values shows correctly.

[image]

How can I force chart to show all label in fit screen view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing [mpchart example code](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample) the problem is solved. I just need to use this fragment:

```
xAxis.labelCount = xAxisLabel.size()
```